# How can I execute two different jQuery animations right after each other with the same "button"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I press the button I animate my `.header_inner` to move downwards. But how do I make it to go back to its original position when I press the button again or to animate it moving upwards?

Code:

```
<script>
  $('.handler').click(function(){
    $('.header_inner').animate({
        top:"-=-28%",
    }, 300);
});     
</script>
```

I want my `.header_inner` to animate its way back again when I press the button again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a boolean variable that indicates whether the last movement was upwards or downwards:

```
var upwards = false,
    newTop;
$('.handler').click(function(){
    if (upwards) newTop = '28';
    else newTop = '-28';
    $('.header_inner').animate({
        top:"-=" + newTop + "%",
    }, 300);
    upwards = !upwards;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

the same but without global variables:

```
function toggleAnimate(){
    $('.header_inner').animate({
        top:"-=" + ((toggleAnimate.upwards)? '28':'-28') + "%",
    }, 300);
    toggleAnimate.upwards = !toggleAnimate.upwards;
}
toggleAnimate.upwards = false;
$('.handler').click(toggleAnimate);
```

Comment: Yes, definitely avoid outer vars wherever possible.